# Consumable Product data

Tags: database, database-connection, product

I am currently building a data base of consumable products ie..oral hygyne products, bath and body, food, beverages, cleaning products etc..basically I need all products we consume/purchase that are sold in your typical stores, Ralph's, Albertsons, Walmart, CVS, Right Aid, Target etc...so when my users place these certain products in the search bar it can reconize it and begin the search ..I am building an e-commerce site with a while lot of product data.  Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to collect such large amounts of data?

Comment: Just wanna clarify: So you want some clues of how to collect the data of all these consumable products from *these stores*, or any source of data is fine??

Comment: Yes sir!..I would need product picture, product data and information HTML.

Comment: Help would be greatly appreciated!!.Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna try open data

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_data\

*There are many government entities pursuing Open Data in Canada. Data.gov lists the sites of a total of 31 US states, 13 cities, and > 150 agencies and subagencies providing open data; e.g. the state of Maryland, the state of California, US.*